# Disabling the cat command

Tags: r, cat

Suppose I have the following function:

```
## Just an example
f = function() { 
  for(i in 1:10000)
      cat(i)
  return(1)
}
```

When I call `f()` is there a way to stop `cat` printing to the screen (without altering the function in anyway)?

**Reason behind this question**

My students upload their R files. I then run the scripts and check to see if they are correct. Every so often, a student leaves in the `cat` command. This is especially irritating when it's in a long for loop

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Linux, you can use a `sink()` call to `/dev/null`(or to a temporary file on another OS, see `?tempfile`) :

```
sink(file="/dev/null")
f()
sink()
```

Comment: `sink` is very useful. However it will also sink the return value of the function.

Comment: @Sacha the obvious solution to that is to assign the output from `f()` to an object.

Comment: Or in one line `capture.output(x <- f())`

Answer (score 5):

This should work?

```
oldcat = cat
cat = function( ..., file="", sep=" ", fill=F, labels=NULL, append=F ) {}
f()
cat = oldcat
```

Just replace `cat` with an empty `function`, and then set it back on completion

Comment: `cat <- function(...) {}` would be simpler

Comment: or even `cat <- list` as long as `cat` only appears in functions.

Comment: `cat <- list` seems a little obtuse.  I'm sure I'd have to read that 3 or 4 times to remember what I was doing...

Comment: `rm(cat)` would also restore `cat` removing the version in the global environment so that it does not mask the version in base.  Also we can eliminate the need for `oldcat` as it  can always be referenced as `base::cat` .

Answer (score 3):

`capture.output()` with `invisible()` does what you want:

```
f <- function() {
    cat("Hello")
    return(TRUE)
}
f1 <- function() {
    invisible(capture.output(f()))
}
x <- f1()
```

This also works:

```
f2 <- function() {
    tmp <- tempfile()
    sink(tmp)
    on.exit(sink())
    on.exit(file.remove(tmp), add = TRUE)
    invisible(force(f())) 
}
x <- f2()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a funny hack that comments out all the `cat()`'s in a function. Not sure if this gives errors or breaks the function though:

```
foo <- deparse(f)
f <- eval(parse(text=gsub("cat","#cat",foo)))

f()

[1] 1
```

## Edit:

Another option is basically Juba's answer, using sink, but you can use the `Defaults` package to change the default behavior of `cat`. The `file` argument basically sinks its output in a file. So :

```
library("Defaults")
setDefaults(cat,file="sink.txt")

f()
```

Ensures that only output of `cat` and not `print` or so is sinked. However, this drastically reduces the runtime since now a file is opened and closed everytime `cat()` is run.

Comment: Yikes! That first idea will kill your students' code if they've used the letters 'cat' anywhere! Such as a variable called 'catalog'...

Comment: You should use regular expression for that one: `gsub("^cat$", "#cat", foo)`

Comment: Old old answer. But note this would also break in multiline `cat` calls.

Answer (score 1):

The function `quietly()` from the `purrr` library creates a quiet version of a function:

```
library(purrr)
f <- function() {
    cat("Hello")
    return(TRUE)
}
f2 <- quietly(f)
f2()
#> $result
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $output
#> [1] "Hello"
#> 
#> $warnings
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $messages
#> character(0)
```