# R - suppressMessages / suppressWarnings not working

Tags: r, suppress-warnings

I have tried expressions with suppressMessages(expr), suppressWarnings(expr),
but they keep outputting messages.

eg:

```
suppressWarnings(ksvm(y~., data=data, type='C-svc', cross=5, kernel=kernel))
```

keeps generating this message.

> Setting default kernel parameters

How do I suppress messages from libraries? Is there a way to do this globally?

Have tried:

```
{r messages=FALSE, warnings=FALSE}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the link to the line where the output is generated: https://github.com/cran/kernlab/blob/master/R/ksvm.R#L88

Looking at that we see that the message is displayed with `cat()` not with `message()`. `suppressMessages()` does not suppress the cat output.

There are multiple ways to get rid of the `cat` output. One is to capture the message and then hide it like so:

```
invisible(capture.output(ksvm(...)))
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I am very new to R and this really sucks. I was hoping the libraries would use some sort of logging mechanism which could be easily suppressed. Is there a way to suppress all such "cat", "print" or other outputs from libraries?

Comment: @coolscitist Well I think they are supposed to use `message()`, `warning()` and the like. But some don't. I don't know if they have a reason not to use those or just generally are not aware of standard ways of showing messages to the user. To suppress cat - like mentioned there are multiple tricks you can use. Some can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5310393/1953718

Comment: @coolscitist Also you can try writing your own function `suppressCat()` or something like that. This answer might be helpful for that: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-January/151465.html

Answer (score 4):

If it does not say that it is a warning, you should use `suppressMessages`. Try putting the function call in braces:

```
suppressMessages({ksvm(y~., data=data, type='C-svc', cross=5, kernel=kernel)})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an empty list to the kpar argument.

Like `ksvm(y~., data=data, type='C-svc', cross=5, kernel=kernel, kpar = list())`